# Disable "double tap space for period" for winrt textbox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Windows 8 has a feature for text edit controls that auto-inserts a period after the user double-taps the space bar.

This can be turned on or off at a system level through the "PC Settings/PC and devices/Typing/Add a period after I double-tap the spacebar" setting. (This setting doesn't always seem to be there - on my Surface it is, on my desktop it isn't; I suspect that it's only available on tablet-like devices...)

I need to be able to *disable* this feature for a certain TextBox element in an app I'm writing.

In lieu of an obvious "DisableAutoInsertPeriodsOnSpaceDoubleTap" property, I've tried a couple of things:

**1) Intercepting the space keystroke, inserting the space myself and marking the event as handled, so that it shouldn't get bubbled up:**

```
private void textbox_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Space)
    {
        this.textbox.SelectedText = " ";
        this.textbox.SelectionStart++;
        this.textbox.SelectionLength = 0;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

This doesn't affect the behaviour of the underlying control at all, however if I replace the space with another character, e.g. "*", then the behaviour *is* suppressed.

If I try inserting a "*" and then *overwriting* it with a " ", the behaviour *returns*!

Ok, so it doesn't look promising that I'm going to be able to use that option.

Next thought:

**2) Handle the TextChanged event and overwrite any auto-inserted period with a space.**

At first glance, after a double-tapped space, the period is inserted two characters to the left of SelectionStart, so something like this works:

```
private void textbox_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.spacePressed = e.Key == VirtualKey.Space;
}

private void textbox_TextChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var text = this.textbox.Text;
    var selectionStart = this.textbox.SelectionStart;
    if (this.spacePressed && this.textbox.SelectionLength == 0 && 
        selectionStart > 2 && text[selectionStart - 2] == '.')
    {
        // Move back two characters and overwrite the character there
        this.textbox.SelectionStart -= 2;
        this.textbox.SelectionLength = 1;
        this.textbox.SelectedText = " ";

        // Reposition the cursor back to where it was
        this.textbox.SelectionStart = selectionStart;
        this.textbox.SelectionLength = 0;
    }
}
```

**Great success!**... but only when the text is in the first line of the text box...

The odd thing is that the cursor position is not always consistent after the period has been inserted. It can be anywhere from at the cursor to 2 characters in front. Another problem with this approach is that *sometimes* (I think when the cursor is *at* the location of the period) replacing the period with a space causes the system to lock up, with the underlying control replacing the space with a period, my code replacing that with a space, and back and forth ad-infinitum.

The best outcome for this question is that there's just a simple property I can set somewhere, and I wasted an hour messing around with this. Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variation on the first attempt works  - replacing the space with an "space alternate", e.g. a no-break space, is enough to bypass the period insertion:

```
private void textbox_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Space)
    {
        // Spaces are always output as non-breaking spaces
        this.textbox.SelectedText = "\u00A0";
        this.textbox.SelectionStart++;
        this.textbox.SelectionLength = 0;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

I then added a converter on top of the binding back to source, making sure that the no-break spaces are replaced normal spaces on the way back:

```
public class SpaceReplaceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var text = value as string;
        return text != null ? text.Replace(' ', '\u00A0') : value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var text = value as string;
        return text != null ? text.Replace('\u00A0', ' ') : value;
    }
}
```

Used like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource SpaceReplaceConverter}}" />
```

Hope that helps someone else.